# Context aware Cordova events in Angular Controllers

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova

Say we're using the backbutton event (Android specific), and attach it like so in controller A:

```
app.controller('aController', ['$scope', function($scope){

   function LogicA(){
   //Logic A
   }
   document.addEventListener("backbutton", LogicA, false);


}]);
```

And we want to do different logic in a separate controller:

```
app.controller('bController', ['$scope', function($scope){

   function LogicB(){
   //Logic B
   }
   document.addEventListener("backbutton", LogicB, false);


}]);
```

What is the correct way to handle this so that the active controller's logic would predominate on the backbutton event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I handle this with one method and a global variable.

Example:

```
var backState = false;

function backButton() {
    if(backState === 'LogicA') {
       //do logic a
    }
    elseif(backState === 'LogicB') {
       //do logic b
    }
    else {
       //some default action if needed
    }
}

document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButton, false);
```

Then as needed I can change the value of `backState` and directly affect the function of the back button.

Comment: I've marked as accepted as I decided going down this same route. I like your code organization and clarity.

Comment: I like using this as you can even change the state multiple times in one view. Example: default is 'go back to last view', if a modal is presented, the back button can be set to dismiss the modal, then after the modal is dismissed the default functionality of 'go back to last view' is back in place.